# Silverlight page goes blank when style is in another file

Tags: .net, silverlight

I've styled a Silverlight `DataGrid` control and when the style is in `UserControl.Resources`, it applied to the `DataGrid` correctly. But If I move it to a `Styles.xaml` file and add the following to `App.xaml`,

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/GridStyle.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The page just goes blank after loading and I get the "Error" Icon in the browser status bar.

This is not something to do with the style file not being loaded because several other styles from the 'Styles.xaml' file apply correctly. Only one style causes this error.

Note: The Style has an element with a binding to the viewmodel which is defined in UserControl.DataContext. Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: Check all references in Style.xaml and if you can, open the file in Blend, it will show you more info about errors than Visual Studio

Comment: references are ok. If there is a binding to a viewmodel which is defined in the mainpage.xaml, will that give me a problem?

Comment: What does the binding in the style look like?

Comment: SelectedItem="{Binding Cell.Grid.DataContext.WeightItemSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" on a combobox

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/[Project name];component/Themes/GridStyle.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/[Project name];component/Themes/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```